# TailwindCSS - hide dropdown menu on mobile

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a dropdown menu working fine on large screens but I its still showing on mobile. I want to have all the buttons showing on mobile without the user having to click the dropdown icon.

I tried hiding various elements but I just end up hiding the whole button

```
<div class="p-0">
                                <div class="dropdown inline-block relative">
                                    <button
                                        style={{ color: '#155610' }}
                                        class="bg-white font-semibold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center"
                                    >
                                        <span class="mr-1">Resources</span>
                                        <svg
                                            class="fill-current h-4 w-4"
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                            viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                                        >
                                            <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" />{' '}
                                        </svg>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu absolute hidden text-black pt-1 ">
                                        <li class="bg-white">
                                            <Link to="/Resources">
                                                <div
                                                    style={{ color: '#155610' }}
                                                    class="rounded-t bg-white hover:bg-white py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap"
                                                >
                                                    Blog
                                                </div>
                                            </Link>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="bg-white">
                                            <Link to="/podcast">
                                                <div
                                                    style={{ color: '#155610' }}
                                                    class="rounded-t bg-white hover:bg-white py-2 px-4 block whitespace-no-wrap"
                                                >
                                                    Podcast
                                                </div>
                                            </Link>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: can you provide a code sandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `sm` or `md` prefix to the hidden utility class and `block` as the default utility class as shown:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu absolute block sm:hidden text-black pt-1 ">
```

Sharing an example of your code here:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/8LtU348zi1

Answer (score -1):

are you working with react? then it would be className instead of class

if not there are specific format to apply css on different devices

```
<div class="sm:hidden md:block lg:block" src="...">
```

[Visit here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design) to find more details

if this also not works for you you can add specific class name by using javascript

```
if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
  //Add css in specific div
}
```